# Parsing strings (language strings) within js html library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to seperate the language vars from my html libary but i'm not sure what the best approach for this is.

Currently I got something like this;

```
function putAlertA() {
    alert('This is alert a');
}

function putAlertB() {
    alert('This is alert b');
}

function setAlerts() {
    putAlertA();
    putAlertB();
}
```

Now i want to separate the strings from the functions:

**Solution A**

```
function putAlertA() {
    var strings = getLanguageVars();
    alert(strings[0]);
}

function putAlertB() {
    var strings = getLanguageVars();
    alert(strings[1]);
}

function setAlerts() {
    putAlertA();
    putAlertB();
}

function getLanguageVars() {
    var strings = new Array();
    strings[0] = "This is alert a";
    strings[1] = "This is alert b";
    return strings;
}
```

**Solution B**

```
function putAlertA(strings) {
    alert(strings[0]);
}

function putAlertB(strings) {
    alert(strings[1]);
}

function setAlerts() {
    var strings = getLanguageVars();
    putAlertA(strings);
    putAlertB(strings);
}

function getLanguageVars() {
    var strings = new Array();
    strings[0] = "This is alert a";
    strings[1] = "This is alert b";
    return strings;
}
```

**Solution C**

```
function putAlertA() {
    var strings = window.strings;
    alert(strings[0]);
}

function putAlertB() {
    var strings = window.strings;
    alert(strings[1]);
}

function setAlerts() {
    putAlertA();
    putAlertB();
}

window.strings = new Array();
strings[0] = "This is alert a";
strings[1] = "This is alert b";
```

I think **Solution C** would be the best since I reckon **solution A & B** generates too much overhead in terms of memory consumption and it doesn't look quite logical since the language array is a global var. I'm however a bit hesitant in using `window.`. Not sure it's the right approach how to do this. Maybe there's a better way how to do this? I'm using jQuery

Comment: Some comments: 1) Don't use `new Array()`; 2) Use named string tables (objects where keys have some meaning) array indexes will get confusing; 3) Search, this question has been asked many times before.

Comment: Is this for localization?

Comment: @Chad 1)I'm used to doing new Array() with php and java, JavaScript is different? It's even being recommended on W3schools.... 2) Thing is that i got many language vars which will make it more likely that i accidentally chose one that already exists... And i'm also not very good in choosing new names haha 3) Could you give me a link? I searched for it but couldn't find it. Maybe because I wasn't sure which keywords to chose for it.

Comment: @Jack What do you mean by localization?

Comment: @bicycle perhaps you can tell what i mean from my answer.

Comment: @Jack Yes now i see what you mean. Thanks bro!

Comment: @bicycle W3Schools? Well, thats the problem: http://w3fools.com/ please use [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preference would be a static object, e.g.:

```
l10n = {
    strings: [
        'alert_a': 'this is alert a',
        'alert_b': 'this is alert b'
    ],
    translate: function(key) {
        return this.strings[key];
    }
}
```

To call:

```
alert(l10n.translate('alert_a');
```

The good thing about this approach is that it's easier to extend, for instance, by introducing parameterized localized strings, e.g.:

```
"Hello :name:"
```

To call:

```
l10n.translate('key', {
    name: 'world'
})
// "Hello world"
```

Comment: That's like a get/set! I like that one! I think it also limits the overhead in terms of memory since you're only calling what you need

Comment: +1. I like this approach; especially because you could extend to do culture sensitive date and number formatting.

Comment: @Jack I'm not gonna use it for different languages though. Other languages are just on a different domain. When I however update a script on one domain, i don't want to edit the js files one by one on the other domain as well.

Comment: @bi that's fine I guess, you don't have to :)

Answer (score 1):

The main change I would make is to use strings as keys rather than integers because this is more meaningful. This is really just a special case of choosing a good variable name:

```
  window.strings = {
      alertA: 'This is alert A',
      alertB: 'This is alert B'
  };

  alert(strings.alertA);
```